# Inheriting constructors

Tags: c++, inheritance, gcc, constructor

Why does this code:

```
class A
{
    public: 
        explicit A(int x) {}
};

class B: public A
{
};

int main(void)
{
    B *b = new B(5);
    delete b;
}
```

Result in these errors:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:13: error: no matching function for call to ‘B::B(int)’
main.cpp:8: note: candidates are: B::B()
main.cpp:8: note:                 B::B(const B&)
```

Shouldn't B inherit A's constructor?

(this is using gcc)

Answer (score 603, accepted):

If your compiler supports C++11 standard, there is a constructor inheritance using `using` (pun intended). For more see [Wikipedia C++11 article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Object_construction_improvement). You write:

```
class A
{
    public: 
        explicit A(int x) {}
};

class B: public A
{
     using A::A;
};
```

This is all or nothing - you cannot inherit only some constructors, if you write this, you inherit all of them. To inherit only selected ones you need to write the individual constructors manually and call the base constructor as needed from them.

Historically constructors could not be inherited in the C++03 standard. You needed to inherit them manually one by one by calling base implementation on your own.

---

For templated base classes, refer to this example:

```
using std::vector;
    
template<class T>
class my_vector : public vector<T> {
    public:
    using vector<T>::vector; ///Takes all vector's constructors
    /* */
};
```

Comment: This is quite evil because for over a year that has been no compiler that can actually build the above code :-)

Comment: @Mikhail: Both clang and g++ should now support inheriting constructors:  
http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html  
http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html  
Recommend upvoting this one as the correct answer.

Comment: just asking, would an inherited constructor be able to access/initialize the base class's private members? Or would I have to specify them as protected?

Comment: @Markasoftware The code setting those members still belongs to the base class. The 'using' declaration just means that B gains a constructor which calls through to A's constructor. So your members can be private :)

Comment: MSVC++ still doesn't support inheriting constructors: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx

Comment: @SergeRogatch You are correct, but it seem to be coming eventually: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2015/04/29/c-11-14-17-features-in-vs-2015-rc.aspx

Comment: I am a person from the future! MSVC 2015 claims support.

Comment: Can you use this syntax to only inherit a specific constructor?

Comment: @whoKnows: No, this is all-or-nothing: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration

Comment: Thank you for a link. MUST KNOW!!! Just wanted to share my experiment: using Base::Base; statement should not necessarily reside in public section. It works everywhere, just like friend statement

Answer (score 118):

Constructors are not inherited. They are called implicitly or explicitly by the child constructor.

The compiler creates a default constructor (one with no arguments) and a default copy constructor (one with an argument which is a reference to the same type). But if you want a constructor that will accept an int, you have to define it explicitly.

```
class A
{
public: 
    explicit A(int x) {}
};

class B: public A
{
public:
    explicit B(int x) : A(x) { }
};
```

**UPDATE**: In C++11, constructors can be inherited. See Suma's answer for details.

Answer (score 19):

This is straight from [Bjarne Stroustrup's page](http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#inheriting):

If you so choose, you can still shoot yourself in the foot by inheriting constructors in a derived class in which you define new member variables needing initialization:

```
struct B1 {
    B1(int) { }
};

struct D1 : B1 {
    using B1::B1; // implicitly declares D1(int)
    int x;
};

void test()
{
    D1 d(6);    // Oops: d.x is not initialized
    D1 e;       // error: D1 has no default constructor
}
```

note that using another great C++11 feature (member initialization):

```
 int x = 77;
```

instead of

```
int x;
```

would solve the issue

Comment: In general, I wouldn't consider inheriting base class ctors as *shooting yourself in the foot*, but good practice - in those cases where this is possible. The cases where this is is possible are the ones where the subclass does not add members that require construction. However, if one modifies the subclass later and adds members that require initialization in the constructor, one has to change the constructor, too - and replace the inheritance by a custom constructor. If one forgets this when adding the subclass members, one shoots into the foot as if not updating a custom ctor.

Comment: Why is this an answer? How comes it has upvotes. Shows you that StackOverflow is not as fair. Shouldnt this be a comment?

Answer (score 16):

You have to explicitly define the constructor in B and explicitly call the constructor for the parent.

```
B(int x) : A(x) { }
```

or

```
B() : A(5) { }
```

Comment: No - as of C++11, you don't have to any more.

Answer (score 8):

How about using a template function to bind all constructors?

```
template <class... T> Derived(T... t) : Base(t...) {}
```

Comment: Probably you should do it with perfect forwarding:

        template < typename ... Args > 
        B( Args && ... args )
        :   A( std::forward< Args >( args ) ... )
        {}

Comment: And you just broke `Derived`'s copy constructor.

Comment: Would Base's constructor have to be templated too? When you call Base(t...), then Base would have to be templated for whatever t is?

Comment: @Zebrafish: No, it doesn't. And even if it was, it wouldn't have to be templated in the same way. This is because when the Derived ctor is instantiated, it calls a Base ctor. This base ctor call is subject to the usual overload resolution given the (instantiated) arguments `t...`. That's why there is a warning about the copy ctor: this will blindly try to call `Base::Base(Derived const& src)`, which could very well slice the Base part of src.

Answer (score 2):

Correct Code is

```
class A
{
    public: 
      explicit A(int x) {}
};

class B: public A
{
      public:

     B(int a):A(a){
          }
};

main()
{
    B *b = new B(5);
     delete b;
}
```

Error is b/c Class B has not parameter constructor and second it should have base class initializer to call the constructor of Base Class parameter constructor

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I make the derived classes "inherit" all the parent's constructors. I find this is the most straightforward way, since it simply passes all the arguments to the constructor of the parent class.

```cpp
class Derived : public Parent {
public:
  template <typename... Args>
  Derived(Args&&... args) : Parent(std::forward<Args>(args)...) 
  {

  }
};
```

Or if you would like to have a nice macro:

```cpp
#define PARENT_CONSTRUCTOR(DERIVED, PARENT)                    \
template<typename... Args>                                     \
DERIVED(Args&&... args) : PARENT(std::forward<Args>(args)...)

class Derived : public Parent
{
public:
  PARENT_CONSTRUCTOR(Derived, Parent)
  {
  }
};
```

Comment: Don't do the first thing and hell don't do the macro. The first part defines copy and move constructor.

Answer (score -1):

derived class inherits all the members(fields and methods) of the base class, but derived class cannot inherit the constructor of the base class because the constructors are not the members of the class. Instead of inheriting the constructors by the derived class, it only allowed to invoke the constructor of the base class

```
class A
{
    public: 
        explicit A(int x) {}
};

class B: public A
{
       B(int x):A(x);
};

int main(void)
{
    B *b = new B(5);
    delete b;
}
```

Comment: This is not an answer. Should be a comment. And is stupid since this is written after the accepted answer. I will downvote this because it is false and will lead people astray. Infact it is the description found in the google search link; so it even leads the google ai a stray.