# c++ constructor using incorrect parameter type to construct object

Tags: c++, inheritance, interface, constructor, reference

I have the following hierarchy:

I have the following hierarchy:

```
GameStateBaseClass -> IGameStateInterface -> IntroState
```

[image]

The issue I am having is when I instantiate a IntroState using a GameEngine reference (as I define in GameStateBaseClass) I get the following error:

> Error 1   error C2664: 'IntroState::IntroState(const IntroState &)' :
>   cannot convert parameter 1 from 'GameEngine' to 'const
>   Short::IntroState &'

Within GameStateBaseClass I define a constructor that takes a const GameState reference, and in main.cpp I pass in an instance of a game engine. Why on earth is it trying to convert my GameEngine parameter to a IntroState reference?

Here's the corresponding code:

GameStateBaseClass.hpp

```
class GameStateBaseClass
{
    public:
        GameStateBaseClass(const GameEngine &instance);
    private:
        GameStateBaseClass(void); // = delete; // c++1x
        GameStateBaseClass(const GameStateBaseClass &instance); // = delete; // c++1x
        GameStateBaseClass operator=(const GameStateBaseClass &instance); // = delete; // c++1x

        // private members
        const GameEngine &game_engine_instance;
}
```

GameStateBaseClass.cpp

```
GameStateBaseClass::GameStateBaseClass(const GameEngine &instance) 
    : game_engine_instance(instance) {
}

// IGameStateInterface.hpp 
class IGameStateInterface : GameStateBaseClass
{
     public:
        virtual void Init() = 0;
        virtual void Cleanup() = 0;
        ... // other virtual void methods...
}
```

IntroState.hpp

```
class IntroState : public IGameStateInterface
{
    virtual void Init() {}

    virtual void Cleanup() { }

    // other empty bodies 

}
```

Here's the game engine .hpp file,
GameEngine.hpp

```
// forward declaration
class IGameStateInterface;

class GameEngine
{
    public:
        void Init();
        void CLeanup();

        void SetState(IGameStateInterface *state);
        void AddState(IGameStateInterface *state);

        // ... other methods for the engine
};
```

In my main.cpp, I have the following:

```
int main(...) {

GameEngine engine_intance;

// instantiate the engine
engine_instance.Init();

// load the intro state
engine_instance.AddState(new IntroState(engine_instance)); 

// main loop
....

return 0;
}
```

I would like it to just use the constructor I defined in GameStateBaseClass, the one that takes a const GameEngine reference to construct the IntroState, not the one it's trying to convert too in the error message.

Any ideas?

The issue I am having is when I instantiate a IntroState using a GameEngine reference (as I define in GameStateBaseClass) I get the following error:

> Error 1   error C2664: 'IntroState::IntroState(const IntroState &)' :
>   cannot convert parameter 1 from 'GameEngine' to 'const
>   Short::IntroState &'

Within GameStateBaseClass I define a constructor that takes a const GameState reference, and in main.cpp I pass in an instance of a game engine. Why on earth is it trying to convert my GameEngine parameter to a IntroState reference?

Here's the corresponding code:

GameStateBaseClass.hpp

```
class GameStateBaseClass
{
    public:
        GameStateBaseClass(const GameEngine &instance);
    private:
        GameStateBaseClass(void); // = delete; // c++1x
        GameStateBaseClass(const GameStateBaseClass &instance); // = delete; // c++1x
        GameStateBaseClass operator=(const GameStateBaseClass &instance); // = delete; // c++1x

        // private members
        const GameEngine &game_engine_instance;
}
```

GameStateBaseClass.cpp

```
GameStateBaseClass::GameStateBaseClass(const GameEngine &instance) 
    : game_engine_instance(instance) {
}

// IGameStateInterface.hpp 
class IGameStateInterface : GameStateBaseClass
{
     public:
        virtual void Init() = 0;
        virtual void Cleanup() = 0;
        ... // other virtual void methods...
}
```

IntroState.hpp

```
class IntroState : public IGameStateInterface
{
    virtual void Init() {}

    virtual void Cleanup() { }

    // other empty bodies 

}
```

Here's the game engine .hpp file,
GameEngine.hpp

```
// forward declaration
class IGameStateInterface;

class GameEngine
{
    public:
        void Init();
        void CLeanup();

        void SetState(IGameStateInterface *state);
        void AddState(IGameStateInterface *state);

        // ... other methods for the engine
};
```

In my main.cpp, I have the following:

```
int main(...) {

GameEngine engine_intance;

// instantiate the engine
engine_instance.Init();

// load the intro state
engine_instance.AddState(new IntroState(engine_instance)); 

// main loop
....

return 0;
}
```

I would like it to just use the constructor I defined in GameStateBaseClass, the one that takes a const GameEngine reference to construct the IntroState, not the one it's trying to convert too in the error message.

Any ideas?

Comment: You have no `IntroState::IntroState(GameEngine&)` or similar. So how is the `new IntroState(engine_instance)` supposed to work?

Comment: Your question is somewhat messy and includes 10 different code snippets. You should try to extract a problem to a minimal scenario and otherwise perhaps use gist to publish sources when necessary (preferably compilable) like this: https://gist.github.com/1509689

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your class `IntroState` does not have a constructor that can take an argument of the type `GameEngine`, therefore, this fails:

```
new IntroState(engine_instance)
```

[Constructors are not inherited](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347358/inheriting-constructors), so the fact that the base-class `GameStateBaseClass` has such a constructor does not imply the same for `IntroState`. You have to explicitly write such a constructor:

```
class IntroState : public IGameStateInterface
{
public:
    IntroState(GameEngine & engine) : IGameStateInterface(engine) {}
};
```

Then, `IGameStateInterface` needs such a delegating constructor as well.

The compiler tries find a constructor that takes one argument, and the only one it finds is the compiler-generated copy-constructor of `IntroState`, which has this signature:

```
IntroState(const IntroState&)
```

Hence the error message.

Comment: Hmm I had no idea constructors weren't inherited!