# Passing arguments through an abstract class to the grandparent class’s constructor

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have a class `Grandparent` which is provided by a library. I’d like to define an interface for subclasses of `Grandparent`, so I created an abstract subclass called `Parent`:

```
class Grandparent {
    public:
        Grandparent(const char*, const char*);
};

class Parent : public Grandparent {
    public:
        virtual int DoSomething() = 0;
};
```

The constructor for `Grandparent` takes two arguments. I’d like my child class, `Child`, to also have a constructor with two arguments, and just pass these to the constructor for `Grandparent`… something like

```
class Child : public Parent {
    public:
        Child(const char *string1, const char *string2)
        : Grandparent(string1, string2)
        {}

        virtual int DoSomething() { return 5; }
};
```

Of course, `Child`’s constructor can’t call its grandparent class’s constructor, only its parent class’s constructor. But since `Parent` can’t have a constructor, how can I pass these values to the grandparent’s constructor?

Comment: Why do you think that `Parent` cannot have a constructor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Parent` can certainly have a constructor. It must, if it's going to call the `Grandparent` constructor with any parameters.

There's nothing forbidding abstract classes from having constructors, destructors, or any other kind of member function. It can even have member variables.

Simply add the constructor to `Parent`. In `Child`, you'll call the `Parent` constructor; you can't "skip a generation" with constructor calls.

```
class Parent: public Grandparent
{
public:
  Parent(char const* string1, char const* string2):
    Grandparent(string1, string2)
  { }
  virtual int DoSomething() = 0;
};
```

Comment: For some reason I thought that abstract classes couldn’t have constructors. Of course your solution worked great. Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps you're thinking of *interfaces* in some other language, like Java, C#, or Delphi. C++ doesn't have a separate interface type.

Comment: Yes, I’m coming from Objective-C, and I’m still working out the differences between interfaces and abstract base classes.

Answer (score 2):

If you want something else than the default constructor for Parent, you need to provide it.

Check out this [question about inheriting constructors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347358/inheriting-constructors)

Also, see this [example of an abstract class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c8whxhf1.aspx)