# child class hides parent class's constructor

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have a class `C` that inherits class `P`

```
template <typename T>
class P{
  public:
  P();
  P(T* sometype);
};

class C: public P<sometype>{

};
```

Now would `C` hide `P(sometype*)` constructor ? But I need that `P(ometype*)` constructor be available in `C`. Do I need to write another `C(sometype*)` that calls parent constructor ? or there is some easy breakthrough. and I don;t want to use `C++11` features.

Comment: The parent class constructor creates a parent object. There's no point _inheriting_ that in a child class: its constructor should obviously create a child object. The parent class constructor is _available_, though, to create the parent object inside the child object.

Comment: Not quite a duplicate, but very close: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/347358/inheriting-constructors

Comment: In C++03 that cannot be done without creating a constructor in C that will manually forward the call, in C++11 you can have inherited constructors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, constructors are not inherited. You need to write a new one for `C`:

```
template <typename T>
class C : public P<T> {
public:
  C(T* sometype) { /*...*/ }
};
```

Note, in addition, that your use of the identifier `sometype` is inconsistent. In the case of `P` you use it as a variable name, in `C` it is a typename, but one that hasn't been declared.

Another question is what the constructor of `C` is going to do about the `sometype` object. I suspect it is going to do exactly what `P`'s constructor does, and since you need to call the constructor of the base class anyway, your implementation of the `C` constructor will most likely look like this:

```
template <typename T>
class C : public P<T> {
public:
  C(T* sometype):P<T>(sometype) { }
};
```

As a final remark: C++11 actually offers constructor inheritance as a feature. Since you are not interested in using C++11 features (which is a pity though indeed), and since the feature is not yet implemented by many compilers I won't go into the details. The reference to the feature definition is [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2540.htm).

Answer (score 1):

If you need to specify your **baseclass** `type T` through your **sub-type**, try this:

```
template<typename T>
class C : public P<T> {
  public:
    C(T* pT): P(pT) {}
}

int* pMyInt;
C<int> myClass(mMyInt);
```

Comment: What is the benefit to treat C as template instead ?

Comment: Treating C as a template allows you to specify the **type of T** in the baseclass when you construct a **C** object

Comment: You have a typo, it should be `class C : public P<T> {`

Answer (score 0):

You should write a constructor of C that takes the same parameter and passes it to its parent class, like this:

```
C(T* sometype)
    : P(sometype)
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Now would C hide P(sometype*) constructor ?

Yes, in the sense that `C` does not inherit P's constructors. So `C` will not have the constructor of the parent class available to users of the class.

> But I need that P(ometype*) conctructor be available in C

That's possible: you simply call it directly:

```
P::P(sometype*)
```

Comment: wasn't there an using keyword that pulls the constructor from parent class ?

Comment: @DiproSen yes, but only in C++11. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Object_construction_improvement).