# C++ construtor with multi level inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor

I'm trying to do multiple levels of inheritance and call the base constructor however the complier cannot find my base constructor..

`no overloaded function takes 8 arguments`

where have I gone wrong in my code?

The .cpp for my base class constructor
defaults 10 member variable ints to 0

```
Baseclass::Baseclass(void) : m_1(0),m_2(0),
                                   m_3(0),m_4(0),
                                   m_x(0),m_y(0),
                                   m_5(0),m_5(0),
                                   m_7(0), m_8(0)
{
}

Baseclass::Baseclass(int _1,int _2,int _3, int _4, int _5,int _6, int _7, int _8)
                                 : m_1(_1),m_2(_2),
                                   m_3(_3),m_4(_4),
                                   m_x(0),m_y(0),
                                   m_5(_5),m_6(_6),
                                   m_7(_7), m_8(_8)
{
}
```

and in my first subclass header I have

```
class SubclassA:
    public Baseclass
{
public:
    SubclassA(void);
    using Baseclass::Baseclass;
    ~SubclassA(void);
```

follow by the second subclass having:

```
class SubclassB:
    public SubclassA
{
public:
    SubclassB(void);
    using Baseclass::Baseclass;
    ~SubclassB(void);
```

I would then try to initialise a new instance of this class with:

```
 SubclassB(Id,0,100,100,10,100,1,1)
```

I was unsure if  `using SubclassA::SubclassA;` for be valid inside SubclassB but it didn't fix the problem anyhow.

Comment: 1>world.cpp(55): error C2661: `'CWorldEntityPlayerBody::CWorldEntityPlayerBody' : no overloaded function takes 8 arguments`

Comment: Constructors don't get inherited!

Comment: while I know they don't by default, my reading of the C++11 additions and this question + answer made me think it's possible: http://stackoverflow.com/a/434784/1961167

Comment: Did you check if your compiler supports the C++11 standard?

Comment: I hope your parameters aren't actually called 1, 2, 3 etc. That's just for the example, right?

Comment: @tomislav-maric using VS2012 and I can use shared pointers? not sure how to find the specific compilier version

Comment: @AntonieBlom Yeah I've edited them to clear that up, but they aren't simply _1 in the code

Comment: @WillHutchinson in your code snippet you call the class `SubClassB` and in the following error message you write `CWorldEntityPlayerBody`, typo?

Comment: @claptrap Nah I had changed the variable & class names to make my question more generalized and I just pasted the errors unedited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your error message, I guess you're using Visual Studio? It does not support inheriting constructors.

See: http://wiki.apache.org/stdcxx/C%2B%2B0xCompilerSupport

It seems Gcc 4.8 is the only compiler supporting this at the moment.

Comment: ooh. Constructor inheritance is possible now? I am liking C++11 more and more. I have to check the new documentation.

Comment: Thanks, I guess this has cleared it up! I'll try @AnuragKalia's answer below for a possible workaround

Answer (score 1):

If you don't give any arguments, the superclass default constructor is called implicitly. To pass on arguments, you have to make an explicit parameterized constructor of subclass like this -

```
SubclassA::SubclassA(int a, int b, int c, int d, int e, int f, int g, int h) 
: Baseclass(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h)
{}
```

On the same lines, make another constructor for class `SubclassB` using this constructor of `subclassA`. You cannot use references to `Baseclass` as you did in `SubclassB` because you can only give references to immediate superclass in the hierarchy.

All this has to happen because constructors are not inherited by subclasses in C++ in C++03 standard. In compilers supporting that standard or before, they have to be explicitly called by the subclass' constructor. Since your compiler seems to not support C++11, you have to make do with this now.

**(Updated)**

Comment: Constructors **do** get inherited in _C++11_ if one does `using SuperBaseClassName::SuperBaseClassName`. The OP's compiler just does not implement it yet

Comment: His compiler does support a notable subset of _C++11_, such subset does not happen to contain _inheriting constructors_

Comment: His compiler supports flimsy sets of features. I am waiting for C++11 since the day I knew initializer lists would be a part of it. Yet, it is not there in Visual Studio yet. I feverishly hope they don't take much time in revising their compiler, else they would lose a (free-loading) customer.

Comment: His compiler already supports _initializer lists_, is their implementation of the standard library which doesn't yet support them, but you are free to use them with your own types...

Comment: Really?!! *runs away to astonished* (to be continued...)