# Why C++ Don't Use Parent Class Constructor?

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor, initialization

I wondering why in c++ can't use parent class constructor for an specific signature, in case that derived class miss that?

For example in below sample, I can't initialize `dd` object with `std::string`.

```
#include <iostream>


class Base
{
    int num;
    std::string s;
public:
    Base(int _num){ num = _num;}
    Base(std::string _s){ s = _s;}
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
    Derived(int _num):Base(_num){}
};

int main()
{
    Base b(50);
    Derived d(50);
    Base bb("hell");
    Derived dd("hell"); // <<== Error
    return 0;
}
```

With **Inheritance** I expect to extend a class and not losing previous functionality but here I feel losing some.

In a more practical example, I create my version of `std::string` but It doesn't behave like a `std::string` in some cases :

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>


class MyString: public std::string {
public:
    void NewFeature(){/* new feature implementation*/}
};

int main()
{
    MyString s("initialization");   // <<== Error: I expect to initialize with "..."
    cout<<s;                        // <<== Error: I expect to print it like this.
    return 0;
}
```

Can somebody give some explanation ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to inherit the constructors too, you need to tell the compiler in your code:

```
class Derived : public Base {
  public:
    using Base::Base;  // <- Makes Base's constructors visible in Derived
};
```

As for *"Why do I need to do this?"*: The cheap answer is: Because the standard says so.

Why it does that is speculation (if you do not ask the committee members themselves). Most likely they wanted to avoid "surprising" or "un-intuitive" code-behavior.

Comment: Although `using std::string::std::string` doesn't work, I need the `why` of this problem. why `Inheritance` smells here .

Comment: @Emadpres See [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bc7ea27f32f4594c)  for a working syntax for `std::string`. (Pretty much what I wrote in the answer. :) )

Comment: I'm actually surprised. They wrote a special case into the standard to make things like `using std::string::string` work (recall that `std::string` is actually a typedef for a particular specialization of `std::basic_string`...)

Comment: I think my compiler (VS2012) use pre-c++11 standard. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @BaummitAugen How about `cout<<s;`. I should do some another work to make it work and so on ?

Comment: @Emadpres If `operator<<` should do the same as for `std::string`, no additional work is required (you just call the `operator<<` of `std::string` this way). If it should do something special, you need to add an appropriate overload `std::ostream& (std::ostream&, const MYString&);`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough rep to flag as duplicate, but [Inheriting constructors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347358/inheriting-constructors) answers this sufficiently.

Basically, pre-C++11 it was in the standard to **not** allow constructor inheritance. C++11 has changed this and you can now inherit constructors.