# Automatically implementing a constructor which calls a specific base class constructor

Tags: c++

```
class A
{
    A(int a);
};

class B : public A
{
    using A::A; // Shorthand for B(int b) : A(b) {}?
};

int main()
{
    B b(3);

    return 0;
}
```

Is there some way to accomplish what the above program seeks to (to make B have a constructor with the same parameter's as a base class')? Is that the correct syntax for it?

If so, is it a C++11/14 feature, or can it be done in C++03?

Comment: The name of the feature is *inheriting constructors*.

Comment: Possible dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/a/434784/16287

Comment: [yup](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d7673932fe4ae67c)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there some way to accomplish what the above program seeks to (to make B have a constructor with the same parameter's as a base class')?

Yes, there is. Using *inheriting constructors*:

```
using A::A;
```

> Is that the correct syntax for it?

Yes.

> If so, is it a C++11/14 feature, or can it be done in C++03?

This feature was introduced in C++11. It is not valid in C++03.

For more information, see the relevant section of this [*using declaration*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration) reference.

Comment: Note that this compiles in VS2013 but doesn't actually do anything ([VS14 finally got around to implementing them](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2014/06/11/c-11-14-feature-tables-for-visual-studio-14-ctp1.aspx)).

Comment: haha, I would need this to work in VS2010/12/13, not to mention some old HP-UX/AIX compilers, so I guess it's a no go for me.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, exactly like that (once I cleaned up your unrelated errors):

```
struct A
{
    A(int a) {}
};

struct B : A
{
    using A::A; // Shorthand for B(int b) : A(b) {}?
};

int main()
{
    B b(3);
}
```

([live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/59606d0fac973d77))

These are called *inheriting constructors*, and are new since C++11.