# Inheriting constructor from QObject based class

Tags: c++, qt, inheritance, qobject

I have a class called `MiscData` that inherits `QObject` and has a member variable (a model). And then bunch of other classes that inherit `MiscData` and reimplement its virtual function to populate the model. So it looks like this:

```
class MiscData : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MiscData(QObject *parent = 0);
    QAbstractItemModel &model();
private:
    virtual void loadData() = 0;
private:
    QStandardItemModel m_Model;
}
```

and one of the descendant looks like this:

```
class LogData : public MiscData
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    using MiscData::MiscData;
private:
    virtual void loadData() override;
}
```

I know that I must use an explicit constructor for `MiscData` because it initializes the model member variable. But I am wondering whether it is safe to use `using` directive in the derived class to inherit `MiscData`'s constructor like this.

EDIT: Based on the answer it seems to be fine event to use `using QObject::QObject` in the MiscData too.

Comment: It is safe. `MiscData::MiscData` is public. What problem do you have?

Comment: @SaZ I have no problem yet. :-) I was just wondering whether it is safe to do this when there is QObject in the inheritance tree and the Q_OBJECT macro. I did not know whether the constructor of a QObject derived class must be explicit in all derived classes (for setting properties for instance) or I can inherit it as well like I showed.

Comment: In your case, next ctors will be called: `QObject( nullptr )` -> `MiscData(0)` -> `LogData()`.

Comment: Based on your edit: `MiscData`'s constructor will not be explicit then, since `QObject` has exactly one constructor, which is not explicit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like what you are doing is perfectly right since C++11.

See [Inheriting constructors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347358/inheriting-constructors) and [C++11 Object construction improvement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Object_construction_improvement).

> Note that this is an all-or-nothing feature; either all of that base class's constructors are forwarded or none of them are.

Answer (score 3):

You can call the base class' constructor in the initializer list.

```
class LogData : public MiscData
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit LogData(QObject *parent = 0) : MiscData(parent) {};
private:
    virtual void loadData() override;
}
```

where `MiscData`'s constructor should pass `parent` the to `QObject` the same way:

```
class MiscData : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MiscData(QObject *parent = 0) : QObject(parent) {};
    QAbstractItemModel &model();
private:
    virtual void loadData() = 0;
private:
    QStandardItemModel m_Model;
}
```

The constructor's definition can be moved into the `.cpp` file if you want.

`using` just makes stuff available and does not call anything.

Comment: I do call the QObject constructor in the initializer list and I can do the same for the derived classes (calling MiscData constructor) but I wanted to avoid it in the derived classes where I usually don't need it. Hence my question whether it is safe to inherit constructor of QObject derived class or I should rather use explicit constructor in all QObject derived classes. In other words: I may not need the constructor but QObject/Q_OBJECT related stuff might!

Comment: So your real question is will the explicit keyword carry over when inheriting constructors? I think yes :)

Comment: I never came across this usage of `using`. See my other answer. This one only holds for pre C++11 code.