# Derived class initialization with parameter of another derived class

Tags: c++11, inheritance, polymorphism, operator-overloading, new-operator

I am new in Abstract classes so please excuse any ignorant mistakes

The exercise is given from my school, so the main.cpp file is to be used, almost as it is

I am trying to create a simple calculator in Eclipse using C++11

There exists a simple Abstract class with two virtual methods.

The two derived classes are simply the "Result" and the "Const" classes.
This is the header file of the Abstract class called

> Expression.h

```
class Expression
{
public:
    Expression();
    virtual ~Expression();
   //methods
};
```

Following is the source file of Expression

> Expression.cpp

```
#include "expression.h"
#include <iostream>

Expression::Expression(){}
Expression::~Expression(){}
```

Then I have created two classes called Const and Result

> Const.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include "expression.h"

class  Const : public Expression
{
public:
    Const(int value);
    //inherited methods
private:
    int value;
};
```

and the source file

> Const.cpp

```
#include "expression.h"
#include "Const.h"

Const::Const(int x)
{
    value=x;
};

//inherited methods
```

> Result.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include "expression.h"
#include "Const.h"

class  Result : public Expression
{
public:
    Result(Const& c);
    //inherited methods
private:
    double value;
};
```

> Result.cpp

```
#include "expression.h"
#include "Result.h"
Result::Result(Const& c)
{
    value=c.point;
};
//inherited methods
```

So what i need is to understand

> main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "expression.h"
#include "const.h"
#include "result.h"
void testResult()
{
    Result  res (new Const(4));
    //Here an inherited method will be used to print the contents of object res
}
int main()
{
    testResult();
    return 0;
}
```

The problem i can't solve is the line

```
Result res (new Const(4));
```

The error i get is

> **Conversion from 'Const* to non-scalar type 'Result' requested**

The thing is that what is described in this line should be used as it is, and i can't seem to find exactly what it is.

**EDIT**

The question as asked firstly was apparently misleading due to my fault, tried to fix the question so as to describe exactly my problem

Comment: Try provide a [mcve], this will not only let other people read but also help you find the root of the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You started correctly, by creating a common base class for both `Const` and `Result`, but then completely ignored it.
All your problems are indeed in this line:

```
Result  res = (new Const(4));
```

First of all, operator `new` in C++ returns a pointer, not a reference. Also, this would be a good place to make use of your base class:

```
Expression* res = new Const(4);
```

Since you declared methods `evaluate()` and `print()` as `virtual`, the object `res` is pointing to will be correctly resolved as an instance of `Const` when you call `res->print()` or `res->evaluate()`.

This will use `Const` version of `print()`. If you want to use the `Result` version - abstract classes won't help you here, you need to use casting. Create your own `operator=(Const &)` in `Result` or `operator Result()` in `Const`.

Comment: I think your answer came closer to my problem, i suspect the line i cna't decipher is a new-operator overload, but am not sure
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Situation in your edited question is simplier, although I believe the error would now be about conversion from `Const*` to `Const&`, wouldn't it? Modifying constructor of `Result` to take pointer instead of reference should solve it - even though the parameter being a reference makes much more sense, but since you cannot change `main()`... Just remember that object of type `Result` now takes ownership of newly created `Const`s and you have to `delete` them when you're done with them.

... And I still don't see where the base class would come into play.

Comment: Since the constructor is also inherited and ought to have the same parameteres with the base class, should i create a second one which takes pointer? 
That means that while having `Result();` i should create `Result(Const*)?`

Comment: Constructors could not be inherited until C++11, and even now require specific syntax (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/434784/8087509)). I don't know your exact requirements, but if this line: `Result res (new Const(4));`

is to stay that way, I don't see an option other than overloading constructor.

Comment: Thanks for explaining me what the problem is

I did some research based on the material you gave me, altough there is another problem

Out of all the examples there was no overloaded constructor who took as parameter another class, even more specifically of another derived class 
I think i am coming to a dead end here

Comment: Not sure what the problem is, in a similar manner to your existing `Result(Const& c);` you can declare a constructor accepting a pointer: `Result(Const* c);` or `Result(Expression* c);`. Then, in constructor body you would use operator `->` instead of `.` to dereference the pointer `c`.

Comment: I can't thank you enough for helping me.
Firstly `Result(Const* c)` wouldn't work because it couldn't recognize what Const is even though i had included the Const.h file,nevertheless `Result(Expression* c)` worked. I guess it worked because any base class expression can be used by its derivates(?)

Comment: It worked because that's what the `virtual` specifier is supposed to do - decide at runtime which derived class methods to use when provided with base class pointer. I don't understand why `Result(Const* c)` didn't work, though, maybe I'll check that later.

Answer (score 0):

If you had two derived classes `DerivedClass1` and `DerivedClass2` both derived from some `BaseClass` then to instantiate a pointer to a `DerivedClass1` and use it in polymorphic way use:

```
BaseClass* p = new DerivedClass1;
```

To create a base class pointer to a `DerivedClass2` use:

```
BaseClass* p = new DerivedClass2;
```

And not the:

```
DerivedClass1* p = new DerivedClass2;
```

In your example both `Result` and `Const` classes are derived from `Expression` class hence the confusion. To pass in an argument of `SomeClass&` type, create a temporary object of `SomeClass` and pass it in:

```
SomeClass o;
someFunction(o);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer
Although i am trying to create an instance of DerivedClass2 which takes as a parameter an object of DerivedClass1 in order to use its values
I can't see how your answer can help me though, if it does please explain

Comment: Worked perfectly that way

Answer (score 0):

Class `Result` and `Const` are two different classes. This means the type conversion

```
Result *res = (new Const(4));
```

is not possible. To do what you want, since both classes inherit from `Expression`, do:

```
  Expression * res = new Result( objConst);
```

Where `objConst` is a `Const` object.

Answer (score 0):

One issue is that

```
double point= value;
```

doesn't initialize your member, but a new unused local variable.

just do

```
point = value;
```