# Inherit default values for arguments in the function's declaration from a base class

Tags: c++, inheritance, threadpool, wrapper, poco-libraries

I am trying to write a wrapper class for the [Poco](https://pocoproject.org/) functions that I use.

Here is my code:

```
//PocoWrapper.h
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Poco/Task.h>
#include <Poco/TaskManager.h>
#include <Poco/ThreadPool.h>

namespace myNamespace{

class ThreadPool : Poco::ThreadPool{};

}
```

Now if I include PocoWrapper.h in another script, I should be able to use:

```
myThreadPool = new myNamespace::ThreadPool(1,4);
```

But This gives the error:

```
//error: C2661: 'myNamespace::ThreadPool::ThreadPool' : no overloaded function takes 2 arguments
```

However, if I use:

```
myThreadPool = new Poco::ThreadPool(1,4);
```

It compiles fine. Therefore the problem must be that it is not inheriting the default values for the functions from the Poco::ThreadPool Class.

The ThreadPool constructor has default values, so it should be able to be used with only 2 arguments. From the [documentation](https://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.ThreadPool.html):

```
ThreadPool(
    int minCapacity = 2,
    int maxCapacity = 16,
    int idleTime = 60,
    int stackSize = 0
);
```

How can I make my wrapper class work with only two arguments, like the base class does?

I am not using c++11.

Comment: Methods are inherited _but_ constructors are a special case. Please, have a look at [SO: Inheriting constructors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/434784/7478597). As this has nothing to do with Poco specifically, it looks like a duplicate.

Comment: Don't you need public inheritance?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inheriting constructors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347358/inheriting-constructors)

Answer (score 1):

You can inherit the base class's constructors by `using` their collective name:

```
namespace Poco {
    struct ThreadPool{
        ThreadPool(int);
        ThreadPool(int,int);
    };
}

namespace myNamespace{

    class ThreadPool : Poco::ThreadPool{
        using Poco::ThreadPool::ThreadPool;  // inherits constructors
    };

}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I now get the error.: " Error C2876: Poco::ThreadPool : not all overloads are accessible". How can I only inherit the public constructors?

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that **constructors are not inherited**. So, there is no a constructor in `ThreadPool` class which accepts two arguments.

On the other hand, when you create `Poco::ThreadPool` class, you are free to use any of its constructors. Note, that according to the [documentation](https://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.ThreadPool.html), there are two constructors and each of them accepts optional parameters, so there is no need to specify a full list of parameters.

You might use [using declaration](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration) to "inherit" constructors:

```
class ThreadPool : Poco::ThreadPool {};
    using Poco::ThreadPool::ThreadPool;
}
```