# Inherit copy/move constructor as constructor from base class in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor

I read [inheriting constructors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347358/inheriting-constructors) question and I broadly understand c++ constructor inheritance.

```
class X;

class A {
    A(const A& a); // (1)
    A(const X& x); // (2)
};

class B : A {
    using A::A;
}
```

Copy constructors are specials so I cannot use (1) to build a B from an A although I can use (2) to build a B form an X;

However I can add a templated constructor in B:

```
template<class...T> B(T... t) : A(t...) {}
```

This templated constructor will allow to build a B form an A.

I want to know **what are the side effects of this method and what constructors does it effectively defines ?**

For instance, can I move an A to a B this way. Do I still need the `using A::A` declaration in B? Do I need to add some std::forward black magic?

Comment: Note that `template<class...T> B(T... t)` is not copy constructor. and even with `T&&`, but in later case, you can have exact match over default copy constructor (`B b(non_const_b);`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what are the side effects of this method and what constructors does it effectively defines ?

It defines only one template c'tor. Its specializations will attempt to initialize `A` with whatever **values** you give it.

> For instance, can I move an A to a B this way.

You aren't forwarding. Since you pass by value, even an explicit `B b{std::move(a)};` will not move the argument into the `A` base.

> Do I still need the using A::A declaration in B?

You may have it. It won't be ambiguous, since non-templates are favored over templates when doing overload resolution. That inherited c'tor will be used in `B b{std::move(a)};` instead (since a const reference can bind to an xvalue). Essentially, the overload being picked may not always be what you want.

> Do I need to add some std::forward black magic?

For the template c'tor? Definitely. Use forwarding references by default. And naturally `std::forward` to do the job of forwarding.

Comment: Ok, so now I use forwarding but on Visual studio 2017, the compiler tries to resolve the default constructor with the template declaration witch fails on std::forward<>. So I have to add B() = default. It works fine on GCC. Considering all this, It seems that I need three lines to do a "complete inheritance" of constructors. Does it seem right to you?

Comment: @GuillaumeGris - Visual studio is notoriously non-conforming when templates are concerned.  GCC is in the right, but you'll need that extra for MSVC.