# Inheritance constructors without C++11

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor, c++03

[Inheriting constructors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347358/inheriting-constructors)

Above link said:

In C++03 standard constructors cannot be inherited and you need to inherit them manually one by one by calling base implementation on your own.

So how to do it and bypass it without C++11?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


class A {   
    public:
        int x;
        explicit A(int _x) {
        x = _x;
        }
};

class B:A {
    public:
    explicit B(int x) : A(x) { 

    }
};


int main(int argc, char** argv) {
     A a(10);
     B b(11);

     cout << a.x;
     cout << b.x;

return 0;
```

}

Comment: Kamil: It means that in your derived C++03 class you have to write a wrapper for each base class constructor, if you want to expose these constructors.

Comment: unusable comments I think...should I use C++11 anyway?

Comment: @KamilWiśniewski - That's an easy one. If you may, then most certainly do.

Comment: @Kamil - The second answer at your link shows *exactly* how you have to do this in C++03 https://stackoverflow.com/a/347362/597607

Comment: Kamil: You should post your non-working code, with explanation of what you expected (and why), and what it actually did instead. Then the question is how to implement what you expected and wanted, plus why your non-working code didn't do that.

Comment: I post it earlier as comment now its on top so what is the problem?

Comment: Now you've put that in the question, it allows [answers that are more directly helpful to you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47731568/inheritance-constructors-without-c11#comment82424365_47731568). For future postings, they can be further improved by including info about what you expected, and what you got instead.

Comment: Now I see the fault thanks, but I want to know too, If inheritance is public its working of course but what should I do if **int x** in base class will be protected?

Comment: The same. Except in order to output its value you'd need a public member function that provides the value.

Comment: I think Im little drunk :) I missed that **public** earlier, but anyway thanks for answers.

Answer (score 0):

To fix the presented code:

- Replace `class B: A` with `class B: public A` to give access to `A::x` in `main`.
- Add `<< endl` or `<< '\n'` to each output statement, to get more readable output.

So, the problems with that code had nothing to do with inheriting constructors.

---

For a C++03 ~equivalent of C++11 constructor inheritance, note first that in C++11 and later you can use *argument forwarding* to *almost* get the effect of constructor inheritance. Since the forwarding is imperfect there is a small difference, namely that literal `0` will be forwarded as an `int` rvalue and not as a nullpointer (when the formal argument is of pointer type). But in practice it will do:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>    // std::forward
using namespace std;

class A
{
public:
    int x;
    explicit A(int _x): x{ _x } {}
};

class B:
    public A
{
public:
    template< class... Args >
    explicit B( Args&&... args) : A{ forward<Args>( args )... } {}
};

auto main()
    -> int
{
    A a{ 10 };
    B b{ 11 };

    cout << a.x << endl;
    cout << b.x << endl;
}
```

This means that in C++03 you can define a single template class with the necessary boilerplate for constructor argument forwarding. Let's call that `Constructor_arg_forwarder_`. Then, with class `A` unchanged, the derived class `B` can look like this:

```
class B:
    public Constructor_arg_forwarder_<A>
{
public:
    template< class Args >
    explicit B( Args const& args)
        : Constructor_arg_forwarder_<A>( args )
    {}
};
```

But what is `Args` then? It is an *argument pack class*, which is known to the `Constructor_arg_forwarder_` class, and must be instantiated in each call of this `B` constructor. That instantiation is in C++03 probably best accomplished by a factory function `args`, and then the `main` function with the instantiations can look like this:

```
int main()
{
    A a( args( 10 ) );
    B b( args( 11 ) );

    cout << a.x << endl;
    cout << b.x << endl;
}
```

For detailed code (it's a *lot* of boilerplate code, covering each possible number of arguments, but happily it only needs to be defined once) see my 2010 blog article “[C++98 constructor arguments forwarding](https://alfps.wordpress.com/2010/05/13/cppx-c98-constructor-arguments-forwarding/)”.