# copying all super-class constructors

Tags: c++, constructor, subclassing

I would like to add a new constructor to an existing class (extending `boost::dynamic_bitset` to allow `const char*` as argument).
As this doesn't seem possible to do directly, I'd be ok with creating a subclass `boost::dynamic_bitset_plus` instead which allows me to add the new constructor. However, the class has a whole bunch of other constructors, which I would like to preserve. Is there a way to do this without explicitly implementing each and every one of them?

Basically I could just do this:

```
namespace boost
{
    template <typename Block, typename Allocator>
    class dynamic_bitset_plus<Block, Allocator> : public boost::dynamic_bitset<Block, Allocator>
    {
    public:
        // new constructor
        explicit dynamic_bitset_plus(const char* s) : boost::dynamic_bitset<Block, Allocator>(std::string(s)) {}
        // existing constructors - boring but needed
        template <typename CharT, typename Traits, typename Alloc>
        explicit dynamic_bitset_plus(const std::basic_string<CharT, Traits, Alloc>& s,
            typename std::basic_string<CharT, Traits, Alloc>::size_type pos = 0,
            typename std::basic_string<CharT, Traits, Alloc>::size_type n = std::basic_string<CharT, Traits, Alloc>::npos,
            const Allocator& alloc = Allocator()) : boost::dynamic_bitset<Block, Allocator>(s, pos, n, alloc) {}
        // and a bunch of others ...
    };
}
```

but I'm looking for a way to avoid specifying all the existing constructors.

I do realize that you could simply write a function that takes a `const char*` and returns a `boost::dynamic_bitset`, or simply call `std::string(...)` whenever creating a new `boost::dynamic_bitset`, but this does get tedious and looks a bit ugly IMO.

Comment: I think you're asking about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347358/inheriting-constructors)?

Comment: @DrewDormann Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Don’t know if this meets your needs, but writing a standalone function that takes a const char* and returns that object is much simpler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `using` directive can pull in the base class constructors. When I tried it I found that it didn't include the default constructor, but that one is easy to include; an empty default contructor will of course call the base-class one implicitly.

```
template <typename Block, typename Allocator>
class dynamic_bitset_plus<Block, Allocator> : public boost::dynamic_bitset<Block, Allocator>
{
public:
    // default constructor
    dynamic_bitset_plus() {}
    // new constructor
    explicit dynamic_bitset_plus(const char* s) : boost::dynamic_bitset<Block, Allocator>(std::string(s)) {}
    // existing constructors
    using boost::dynamic_bitset<Block, Allocator>::dynamic_bitset;
};
```