# Allowing inherting class to use the same function

Tags: c++

I have a Vector class which is inherited by an EulerAngle class. I want to be able to use the operator function from the Vector class on a EulerAngle object without having to rewrite the operator in the EulerAngle class and changing Vector3 to Angle if possible. How could I do this?

```
class Vector3 {
public:  
    float x, y, z;

    // ctors...
    __forceinline Vector3() : x{}, y{}, z{} {

    __forceinline Vector3( float x, float y, float z ) : x{ x }, y{ y }, z{ z } {

    }

    // functions...

    // operators...
    __forceinline Vector3 &operator +=( const Vector3 &other ) {
        x += other.x;
        y += other.y;
        z += other.z;

        return *this;
    }

    __forceinline Vector3 &operator +=( float scalar ) {
        x += scalar;
        y += scalar;
        z += scalar;

        return *this;
    }

    __forceinline Vector3 operator +( float scalar ) const {
       return Vector3( x + scalar, y + scalar, z + scalar );
    }

    __forceinline Vector3 operator +( const Vector3 &other ) const {
       return Vector3( x * other.x, y * other.y, z * other.z );
    }

}

class EulerAngle : public Vector3 {
private:

};

// example, MSVC says this is an error and that there is no suitable conversion from EulerAngle to Vector3
EulerAngle ang = { 1.f, 1.f, 1.f };
ang += 5.f
```

After a few answers I added the following code to make this work. However I still want to know if there is a better way to accomplish this?

```
class EulerAngle : public Vector3 {
public:
    using Vector3::Vector3;

    __forceinline EulerAngle( const Vector3 &other ) : Vector3( other ) {

    }
};
```

Comment: Looks like the issue is with the initialization, and has nothing to do with the `operator+=`. "Inheriting constructors" may help you.

Comment: Potentially useful link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347358/inheriting-constructors

Comment: Sidenote: `__forceinline` might not be as useful as you think. You have to get up reaaaaaaly early in the morning to out optimize an optimizing compiler.

Comment: Ok that fixes it for the example above. However, for this operator it is still saying that there is no suitable conversion. Like when i do `EulerAngle ang2 = ang + 5.f` -> `__forceinline Vector3 operator +( float scalar ) const {
        return Vector3( x + scalar, y + scalar, z + scalar );
    }`

Comment: [Current Code via GodBolt](https://godbolt.org/z/HNqwSp) @aschepler I used the C++11 using keyword for inheritance, but it still has the error.

Comment: @user4581301 it's not about optimization, it just looks stupid in the generated assembly to have a function only for setting member vars.

Comment: `Vector3 operator +( float scalar )` returns a `Vector3 `. `Vector3` can use it's compiler-generated copy constructor to do the construction, but no such luck for `EulerAngle`. I think you'll need a `EulerAngle(const Vector3& in): Vector3(in) {}`

Comment: @user4581301 Ye that works

Comment: Works, but unsatisfying. You should move the code from the godbolt link to your question and see if anyone can come up with a better solution. Just because I don't think there is one doesn't mean there isn't one. Some darn crafty people lurking around this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make use of [*user-defined conversion*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator) from `Vector3` to the type you want with static assertion when it is not inherited from `Vector3`.

```
template<typename T>
operator T() const
{
    static_assert(std::is_base_of<Vector3, T>::value, "T is not inherited from Vector3");
    return T{x,y,z};
}
```

#### [LIVE DEMO](https://godbolt.org/z/3C3JrT)

===============================================================

### ADDON

With `C++20` and the introduction of [*concepts*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts), the above code can be rewritten to:

```
template<typename T>
requires std::DerivedFrom<T,Vector3>
constexpr operator T() const
{
    return T{x,y,z};
}
```

#### [LIVE DEMO](https://godbolt.org/z/DyEBCk)

Comment: You can do that even without `using Vector3::` operators as you do in the demo.

Comment: @Oliort Only for `operator+` and `operator+=` though :)

Comment: You mean not for constructor? Agree. Cool solution!

Answer (score 0):

Add implicit constructor from `Vector3` and `using` for `Vector3` constructor in `EulerAngle` class

```
class EulerAngle : public Vector3 {
    using Vector3::Vector3;
    EulerAngle(const Vector3& from) : Vector3(from) {}
}
```

if you want to do it like this

```
EulerAngle ang = { 1.f, 1.f, 1.f };
ang += 5.f;
EulerAngle ang2 = ang + 5.f;
EulerAngle ang3 = Vector3{ 2.f, 2.f, 2.f } + ang2;
```