# Why doesn’t `std::make_shared` work anymore when the class inherits class `enable_shared_from_this`?

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, smart-pointers, enable-shared-from-this

Why doesn’t `std::make_shared` work anymore when the class `Widget` inherits class `enable_shared_from_this`?

Here is the [code snippet](https://godbolt.org/z/5sh1s9jnY):

```
#include<memory>
#include<vector>
#include<iostream>

class Widget:public std::enable_shared_from_this<Widget>
{
public:
    std::vector<int> vec;
    int var;
};

int main()
{
    auto wp{std::make_shared<Widget>()}; 
    //auto wp1{std::make_shared<Widget>(std::vector{1,2,3}, 9)}; //why his line compiles if class Widget does not inherit class enable_shared_from_this<Widget> 
}
```

**What's more**, `auto wp1{std::make_shared<Widget>(std::vector{1,2,3}, 9)};` [works well](https://godbolt.org/z/M99asbav1) if you remove the inheritance.

**UPDATED**: Both the aforementioned code snippet [do not compile with clang](https://godbolt.org/z/5rPs1GY16).

Answer (score 1):

TED's answer:

> It's because there is a constructor added by `enable_shared_from_this` which removes the possibility to do aggregate initialization. In order to support creating it from `make_shared`, add the necessary constructors:
>
> ```
> public:
>     Widget() = default;
>     Widget(const std::vector<int>& v, int i) : vec(v), var(i) {}
> ```

It works indeed. But I still don't know why there is a constructor added by `enable_shared_from_this`?

Comment: "*I still don't know why there is a constructor added by `enable_shared_from_this`*" - It is because [`std::enable_shared_from_this`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this) contains a `std::weak_ptr` member that has to be initialized.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thank you for the clarification. But I still have a question. Since it is ***`std::enable_shared_from_this` other than `Widget` that contains a `std::weak_ptr`***, should not the said `std::weak_ptr` be initialized in the constructor of the base calss(i.e. `std::enable_shared_from_this`) other than the constructor of the derived class? If I am wrong, please let me know.

Comment: Yes, the `weak_ptr` is initialized in the base class constructor, but [base class constructors are not inherited by derived classes by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347358/). So your `Widget` derived from `enable_shared_from_this` does not have constructors that match your `make_shared()` call unless you explicitly add those constructors to `Widget`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau The question why the inheritance to class `std::enabled_from_this` would suppress the constructor which exists if there is no such inheritance.You see https://godbolt.org/z/M99asbav1 works.

Comment: What exactly is unclear about this? Without the inheritance, `Widget` is an aggregate, and the `make_shared()` statement you are asking about uses aggregate initialization. With the inheritance, `Widget` is not an aggregate, so the `make_shared()` statement requires a constructor to call, which is not inherited.