# Introducing base class constructor into the derived implementation with 'using' does not allow converting base to derived

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

It's a mouthful to describe the problem with words, in code it's much simpler:

```
template <typename T>
struct Vec2
{
    Vec2() = default;
    Vec2(const Vec2&) = default;
};

template <class T>
struct Point : public Vec2<T>
{
    using Vec2<T>::Vec2;
};

void f(const Point<float>&);

void test()
{
    f(Vec2<float>{});
}
```

- `Vec2<T>` has a copy constructor.
- `Point<float>` is derived from `Vec2<float>` and pulls in its constructors.

Expected: `Point<float>` should be constructible from `Vec2<float>`.
Reality: "No known conversion" error (https://godbolt.org/z/boe86f99K). Why?

Comment: It's not clear why `Vec2f` is a class at all.  Why not use `Vec2<float>` or just a typedef?

Comment: `f()` takes in a reference to a `Vec2f`, but you are passing it a `Point<float>` instead. `Point<float>` does not derive from `Vec2f`, it derives from `Vec2<float>` instead, which is not the same type as `Vec2f`.

Comment: Are you expecting that two classes derived from the same class are convertible from each other because they, ehm, *"pull in the constructors"* of the base class?

Comment: @Spencer: it's a class because it defines some extra behavior that's special for floats.

Comment: @MatG: What I expect is described by the 3 bullet points in my question. I expect that `Vec2f` should be constructible from `Vec2<float>`, and it does not seem to be the case.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe See [Inheriting constructors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347358/inheriting-constructors), particularly [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68180595/65863), which allows your code to compile (if you ignore some side effects) - you can even get rid of the type-cast in the `f()` call ([Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/zT9zjKbx8))

Comment: @RemyLebeau: I know that constructors are not inherited. The answer you suggested is a bit odd, and I know this would work if I manually define the conversion constructor, but I don't  want to do that. Why doesn't this answer work in my case? https://stackoverflow.com/a/434784/634821

Comment: @VioletGiraffe So, why not an explicit specialization on `float`?

Comment: @VioletGiraffe "*Why doesn't this answer work in my case?*" - I can't answer that. Either it is a limitation of the standard, or a bug in the compiler. But explicitly declaring the appropriate forwarding constructors works: [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/3vvWxMEqn)

Comment: @RemyLebeau: all 3 compilers agree, so it's very unlikely a compiler error.

Comment: @Spencer: because then I would have to redefine everything instead of just redefining 1 method of the 20 methods of the base class.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe Maybe there is some information at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration that explains your situation?